# How to get the next LocalDateTime from an initial LocalDateTime and a cron expression?

Tags: date, cron, java-8

I have an initial date and a cron expression. How could I find the next date satisfying this cron expression ?.

```
    String cronExpresion = "* * * * * *"
    LocalDateTime initial = LocalDateTime.now()
    LocalDateTime next = ?
```

I tried CronSequenceGenerator and its *next()* method but it uses java.util.Date and I would prefer not to convert LocalDateTime to Date and vice versa. Plus, I've got different result (time between the 2 dates) from several run with a cron like 'every 10 secondes' ...

Any idea ? lib ?

Comment: Have you already looked into this project: https://github.com/frode-carlsen/cron ?

Comment: @Rlarroque not sure I am allowed to use "non-official" kind of library.. unless I remake it by myself, but I'll look into it :)

Comment: I think implementing an algorithm that do this would be too broad for SO, but library recommendations are off-topic here. If you are already using a specific library, you could narrow the question down to that library (edit the question and tags) and get an appropriate answer. Otherwise this question will probably get closed.

Answer (score 4):

Omnicron (https://github.com/intelie/omnicron) seems to satisfy at least some of your requirements:

```
Cron cron = new Cron("*/5 * * * *");
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();

System.out.println("Next execution: " + cron.next(date));
System.out.println("Prev execution: " + cron.prev(date));
```

(Cron::next and Cron::prev accept any Temporal value, not just ZonedDateTime.)

Aside from that, Omnicron is, as a bonus, compatible with Spring's CronSequenceGenerator (https://github.com/intelie/omnicron/blob/master/src/test/java/net/intelie/omnicron/SpringCompatibilityTest.java)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use [CronSequenceGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) from spring.

```
String cronExpresion = "* * * * * *";
Date next = new CronSequenceGenerator().next(new Date());
return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(next.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally Spring with version `5.3.0` published new version of [CronExpression](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) which is not connected to old java time API