# Get next Date that meets conditions in Java

Tags: java, time

I know this should be simple, but I can't find anything on the internet.

Given some conditions, I want to get the next `Date` when they will be met. For example, if conditions are `minute = 01` and `second = 30` and now the time is `15:58:00`, the function should return today at `16:01:30`. How can I accomplish this in Java?

I need to be able to set conditions of, at least, seconds, minutes and hours, but I would like to have the possibility to set one condition to any value (like the example above, that doesn't specify an hour).

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

**EDIT:**
I see there's something that might need clarification: I want to get a Date (or whatever) always *after* the current time that meets conditions. Also, this is for a Minecraft Spigot server, maybe this information can help.

Comment: If by `Date` you meant `java.util.Date`, I recommend you don’t that class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime`or another appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Are you really implementing the functionality of [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in Java? There are already libraries doing that, so you don’t need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @OleV.V. I have already heard about the cron4j library, and that's one of the things I was planning to do. But this still doesn't solve another project I had in mind: I want to make a train "departure board" based on a schedule for a video game. The function should return the exact time when a train will depart, even if the schedule only shows "*:10:00" (at any hour ten). Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, by `Date` i meant `java.util.Date`. Thanks for the information!

Comment: @jnts - `if conditions are minute = 01 and second = 30 and now the time is 15:58:00, the function should return today at 16:01:30` - Why `16:01:30` and not `15:01:30`? Is it because `15:01:30` is earlier than `15:58:00` and you want a later time with the specified minute and second?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash exactly, I want to get the first time when the conditions will be met _after_ the current time.

Comment: If you put this check `if (updated.isBefore(today)) { updated = updated.plusHours(1); }` in my second solution, you will get `2021-02-23T16:01:30`. If you think it has brought you one step closer, you should explore the rich *java.time* API further. In my answer, I've already put a link to the brilliant tutorial by Oracle. Feel free to comment in case you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LocalDateTime#plus...`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) to add duration to get the updated time.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strTime = "15:58:00";

        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(strTime);

        // Today at the specified time
        LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now().with(time);
        System.out.println(today);

        // Today with the added minutes and seconds
        LocalDateTime updated = today.plusMinutes(1).plusSeconds(30);
        System.out.println(updated);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-02-23T15:58
2021-02-23T15:59:30
```

If you want to switch to a different time, you can use `LocalDateTime#with...`

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strTime = "15:58:00";

        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(strTime);

        // Today at the specified time
        LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now().with(time);
        System.out.println(today);

        // Today with the updated minute and second
        LocalDateTime updated = today.withMinute(1).withSecond(30);
        System.out.println(updated);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-02-23T15:58
2021-02-23T15:01:30

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.
```

**Note:** The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: The author don't want to add 1 minute and 30 seconds, she likes to jump to the next timestamp with 1 Minute and 30 seconds ;)

Comment: @Norbert - The question is not very clear. I've provided the OP with both solutions. I'll wait for his/her response and then update the answer if required.

Comment: @Norbert exactly, that's not what I wanted to do. I want to get a time always _after_ the current time that meets conditions defined in a timetable. Check my comment on the question to understand exactly how I want to apply this. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could use streams for this:

```java
Optional<LocalDateTime> firstMatch = 
                         Stream.iterate(
                                  LocalDateTime.now(),
                                  ldt -> ldt.plusSeconds(1L))
                               .filter(
                                  // Insert your condition here
                                  ldt -> ldt.getSecond() == 0) 
                               .findFirst();
```

What this code does is take the current `LocalDateTime` and use it to generate a stream of `LocalDateTime` objects (advancing the time by 1 second each time). Once it encounters a `LocalDateTime` that matches the provided condition, it returns this objects and terminates the stream.

Keep in mind that using this approach will generate a lot of objects if it takes a while for the condition to become true, so it is not very efficient.

If you want to strip the nanoseconds replace `LocalDateTime.now()` by `LocalDateTime.now().withNano(0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My limited knowledge of the language makes it a bit difficult for me to understand your code. Is this similar to having a `while` loop that checks the condition and adds one second if it's not met? What's the advantage of using your method?

Comment: Imho it is more beautiful than a while-loop, but that's only a personal opinion. To explain the code a bit: Jeroen creates an endless Stream of objects. He starts with a date object for now and creates a new object which is 1 second in the future. The stream takes care of the rest and so you get LocalDateTime objects for every second from now on. In the filter you define the condition to filter the stream, but you get every timestamp that meet this, so you have to use findfirst. Then you get the first object that meets your conditions. As mentioned you generate a lot of objects ...

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, this should solve your problem

```
public String nextMeet(int minutes, int seconds) {
    LocalDateTime currentDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    if ((currentDate.getMinute()*60) + currentDate.getSecond() > (minutes*60) + seconds) {
        return (currentDate.getHour() + 1) + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    } else {
        return currentDate.getHour() + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get a time that's always _after_ the current time. I've updated the question to include this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution myself. [This library](https://github.com/intelie/omnicron) can parse a cron expression and return the next time when it will run, which solves most of my issues. (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109740/how-to-get-the-next-localdatetime-from-an-initial-localdatetime-and-a-cron-expre))

Thanks to @OleV.V. for the idea.